# SoftKeyboard not Appearing automatically in Landscape Mode

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have `EditText` with  with   `<requestFocus />` in the XML . when I open the Activity in **Portrait**  Mode  the soft keyboard Appearing automatically,But when I start the activity in **Landscape** Mode the soft-keyboard not appeared automatically .I required  touching  the `EditText` for soft-keyboard .

**Want a soft keyboard to appeared automatically in landscape mode .**

**Android Manifest**

```
<activity
            android:name="activity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
           >
```

whats a problem kindly help me

Comment: you got some advance with the edit of my answer? If you solve your problem don't forget check as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this ,I have test this solution  and it is working  perfect

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mUserNameEdit.requestFocus();

        mUserNameEdit.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                keyboard.showSoftInput(mUserNameEdit, 0);
            }
        },200);
    }
```

Comment: Why you use a postDelayed?

Comment: I could replace `postDelayed` by `post`. This is the same as using `postDelayed` with 0 as 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

for show keyboard use this in the below if conditions,I hope it will work

```
imm.showSoftInput(ed, 0);
```

You can do this by:

For Lanscape

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    //Do some stuff
}
```

For Portrait

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Try with this code

```
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
input.showSoftInput(editText1, RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE | LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN )
```

Comment: explain your answer as well as @Anil Meenugu